# What's with certificate and provisioning profile if I use another mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

The problem is: I have a new mac and need to set it up for development. But my certificate and provisioning profile was left on other machine, so I can't restore them from it anymore.

I found this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW34

But is it necessary to revoke my old certificate and make another one? And how could I do it if I'm not an administrator of our group? 
The last question - what to do with provisioning profile? Should it be changed somehow after I (if needed) change my certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved.

In the same situation there is only one solution: revoke the old certificate and request the new one.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW34

Also, there was an issue "this certificate is not valid yet" - that's because of the difference in time. So I just changed the time at my mac, restarted it and certificate became valid (that's for someone who maybe meet the same issue).

Answer (score 5):

Just open the Keychain Access in your old mac, select Developer and Distribution certificates with private keys all together, click right mouse button, select export, and save anywhere with file type .p12, provide password. Find saved file and copy that to your new mac, open with keychain access, type password you put while saving, and You are good to go ;) Good Luck!

**EDIT** As for provisioning profiles, after you have installed above certificates, you can fetch provisioning profiles from the developer platform using xcode.

**ANOTHER EDIT** Sorry, didn't read the question till end. So, If you export and import the certificates with my way, you don't have to revoke the old certificate, and no need to change the provisioning profiles. If you, revoke your developer and distribution certificates, then you have to modify you provisioning profiles to use new certificate, or create new ones.

Comment: Well this answer is though helpful but I think he is saying for some reason he cannot get hold off his old mac.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't just export it. 
So is this means that I must revoke current certificate and request a new one? And what should I do with provisioning profile?

Comment: If you revoke the certificate you have to create new provisioning profiles or modify existing ones to work with new certificate.

Comment: I kept forgetting how to fix this because Apple kept changing over the years. They added features that made things more complicated than they should be. I love the automation but sometimes we just need to know that we can export private keys and import them on another Mac. That simple!